# What breaks this table layout?

Tags: html, css

Simple contents layout using CSS's table, table-row and table-cell divs:

```
<div style="display:table-cell; border:1px solid blue">
    some content  <!-- this line wrappend in <p> tag in next example -->
    <p>some content</p>
    ...
</div>
```

[two column layout with a nested table on the right](http://jsfiddle.net/J72Lp/2/)

The above example but with left cell's content placed in paragraph (the first row):

[above example but <p> breaking flow of the right table-cell](http://jsfiddle.net/V3WFV/1/)

As you can see, after `<p>` tag put in left cell the right cell is shifted down.
It doesn't matter if I use `<p>` or `<h1>` tag. Assume it does change line-height and 1st row in the adjacent cell is aligned to it.

Can anybody explain this behaviour. How can I prevent shifting of the adjacent cell ?

Comment: Aren't tables better for tabular data?

Comment: @JohnConde probably yes, but I hit this problem and can't explain the strange behaviour. I simply cann't leave it as unresolved mystery.

Comment: @JohnConde They are also good for 'equal height' designs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is **adopting the browser default behavior of a 'table-cell'** by vertically aligning it to inherit, inherit, middle. (Strangely bottom in your page ).

Just add '`vertical-align:top`'  to your CSS will FOR SURE fix your situation.
[jsFiddle forked here](http://jsfiddle.net/WfMYg/)

For example, Firefox [user agent html.css] :

```
tr {
  display: table-row;
  vertical-align: inherit;
}
tbody {
  display: table-row-group;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
thead {
  display: table-header-group;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
tfoot {
  display: table-footer-group;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
/* for XHTML tables without tbody */
table > tr {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
td { 
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: inherit;
  text-align: inherit; 
  padding: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for displaying a working example. Is the *adoption of the browser default behavior of a 'table-cell'* documented somewhere ?

Comment: Humm? A kind of chart of default browser behaviors, that would be nice, but it's vendor specific. A browser can change this from a version to another, etc, etc. If it exists, i want to know.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something to do with the margins the browser is adding to the `<p>` tag automatically try this...

```
div[style*="table-cell"] p:first-child {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Tried but Firefox ignores this.

Comment: @Milche Patern your fix is good, your explanation is faulted. Baseline alignment has to do with text alignment... not always the same as bottom. Also... bottom or baseline is not the default alignment for table-cells it's middle. Furthermore you would see if you painted a box around the table-cell containing the table that it is in line with the other cell... oh well I can't comment on your post.

Comment: @DavidUnric webkit is for Safari/Chrome, so that particular answer won't work in all browsers. Instead just set whatever element you have first in the cell to have a margin top of 0 if you want it to align. I've corrected my answer to work in other browsers.

Comment: @upful Right, it's not bottom, it's inherited (firefox and gChrome check).